# Why won't Mercurial merge my XML files with Beyond Compare?

Tags: xml, mercurial, merge, binaryfiles, beyondcompare3

We have a bunch of XML files in our Mercurial repository.  When we merge changes in those files from one branch to another, **Mercurial complains that some of our XML files are binary**, and asks me to choose between the local and other versions of the file.

I've discovered that [Mercurial thinks any file with a NULL byte in it is binary,](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BinaryFiles) and some of our XML files are encoded as UTF-16, so contain a lot of NULL bytes.  **My default merge tool is Beyond Compare**, which can handle UTF-16 encoded files. I've configured Mercurial [as recommended on the Beyond Compare website](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#mercurial), but **during the merge, Mercurial says:**

> tool bcomp can't handle binary

What gives?  **Why does Mercurial think Beyond Compare can't merge my file?**

Comment: use bcompare.exe not bcomp.exe

Comment: @Preet I am using bcompare.  Unfortunately, Mercurial is never asking Beyond Compare to merge my file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended Mercurial configuration to use Beyond Compare as a merge program looks like this:

```
[merge-tools]
bcomp.executable = C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
bcomp.args = $local $other $base $output
bcomp.priority = 1
bcomp.premerge = True
bcomp.gui = True

[ui]
merge = bcomp
```

According to the [Mercurial docs on merge tools](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#merge-tools), there is a `binary` option that is `False` by default.  **When `binary=True`, it tells Mercurial the tool can merge binary files.**  When I turn that option on, however, Mercurial still won't let Beyond Compare merge the XML files.

A little more research turns up the `premerge` option.  **When `premerge=True`, Mercurial merges internally *first*, and use the merge tool only if there are conflicts to be resolved.**  Unfortunately, Mercurial always fails to merge a binary file.  When a pre-merge fails, Mercurial stops the merge for that file and never launches the merge tool.

The solution would seem to be, then, to also set the `premerge` option to `False`.  Unfortunately, the pre-merge is very helpful because 90% of the time, there aren't any conflicts, and never see your merge tool.  With premerge set to `False`, every time a merge is needed, Beyond Compare opens.  This gets very tedious.

To solve this, **I created a second Beyond Compare merge tool configuration which gets used to merge binary files**.  I set its priority lower than the default `bcomp` tool, so it only gets called when the main `bcomp` tool fails, which is usually just for binary files.  I added these lines to the `merge-tools` section of my mercurial.ini file:

```
bcompbin.executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe
bcompbin.args = $local $other $base $output
bcompbin.gui = True
bcompbin.premerge = False
bcompbin.binary = True
```

One of the side-effects of this is that Beyond Compare will launch to merge binary files for which it can't handle.  I haven't encountered that situation yet, so don't know how to handle it.  I would probably just temporarily comment out my `bcompbin` merge tool.

Comment: You could also use a [merge-patterns] to limit it to xml files.

Comment: Have you considered adding more options to Beyond Compare? In particular, the `/automerge` and `/reviewconflicts` might be what you seek. This will still "open" Beyond Compare, but it will attempt to automatically merge the files, and if successful, just save the merge result and never actually present a window to the user.

Comment: Also, this "answer" should've been an edit to your question, since it sounds like you're still looking for an answer to it.

Comment: @Lasse I'll try the /automerge and /reviewconflicts Beyond Compare options.  And this is the answer because it explains why Mercurial wasn't letting Beyond Compare merge my "binary" XML files.